# Eclispe Tomcat shows one URL and shows another one with 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I got a restful application and for some reason - I could not execute methods from the new package with Java classes cause Tomcat shows 404 error. I have no error for my older classes.

Here is screenshot with comparison of the old class (ManageService) and new one (NewsFeedService)

[image]

These are URLs:

**working one:**
http://localhost:8180/ChatRestNoSQLMaven/rest/MessageService/getDialog/8bea7f62-8bff-486c-a2bf-a2f989d0c9a8/c95aaad7-7ceb-408d-86a1-15089c399430

**failed one:**

http://localhost:8180/ChatRestNoSQLMaven/rest/NewsFeedService/hello

> HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
>
> type Status report
>
> message Not Found
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

I made Maven clean and install command, made uninstall/install of the Eclipse Tomcat server, made Project -> Build All, but no results.
What could be a reason?

Tomcat Server startup log:

```
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ChatRestNoSQLMaven' did not find a matching property.
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.9
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 5 2016 20:18:12 UTC
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.9.0
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_112-b15
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\akworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\akworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\akworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\akworkspace\EccentexQAver2\apache-ant-1.10.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Users\akise\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\WINDOWS\System32;;.
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8180"]
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2294 ms
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.9
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:27 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8180]
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
Apr 11, 2017 8:37:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18433 ms
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>REST Chat</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.account,rest.message,rest.friends</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
         </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is it odd, is there any stack trace?

Comment: Also, please provide your Tomcat log during start up so we can see how the services are being bound.

Comment: @JUANCALVOPINAM Error added

Comment: @JonSampson log added

Comment: What's in your `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `<param-value>` to find all the classes that you define within of the `rest` package, it mean that you can remplace this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>rest.account,rest.message,rest.friends</param-value>
</init-param>
```

for this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>rest</param-value>
</init-param>
```

With this config you can avoid adding each new package to `<param-value>`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>      <init-param>
>         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
>         <param-value>rest.account,rest.message,rest.friends</param-value>
>      </init-param>
> ```

Your `param-value` text content should also list the `rest.newsfeed` package.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your port in eclipse server configuration and server.xml file. Please check port number are same in both